# Unable to add php within js file

Tags: javascript, php, magento-1.7

I have a below script, which i need to add in a .js file.

```
 jQuery( ".followlink" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
$k.dialog({
    title: ' ',
    backgroundDismiss: true,
    content : "<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/followup-popup.phtml')->tohtml();?>"

});
    $k('.jconfirm-scrollpane .container').addClass('follow-container');
});
```

I get error marked on this line `<?php echo..`, can anyone tell how to add this inside the JS file.

I have encloded the entire snippet inside the `script` tag.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: You can't add php code in .js file.

Comment: It should be a `.php` file to begin with. You can't exactly run php from a `.js` file.

Comment: Also, you have quotes at the end of your `content` line, but not at the beginning.

Comment: And as @JamesWong said, the whole file needs to be `.php` for this to work.

Comment: There is no error thrown , but there is a red mark in the editor @AndroidNoobie

Comment: Do this in your html files: `<script>var content = "<?php echo json_encode($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/followup-popup.phtml')->tohtml());?>"</script><script src="yourjsfile.js"></script>` and have `content: content` in the js file

Comment: The problem is i am using Magento, so i need to reference this js file in the local xml , but i cant reference the phtml file

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one way,
give element property like `data-content` and then in content label just put $(this).data("content"); so, Code should look like below:

```
jQuery( ".followlink" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
$k.dialog({
    title: ' ',
    backgroundDismiss: true,
    content: jQuery( ".followlink" ).data("content"),

});
    $k('.jconfirm-scrollpane .container').addClass('follow-container');
});
```

Comment: What about the php line :  php echo json_encode($this->getLayout()->...

Comment: u don't have to encode in json just simply put content on element data-content and jquery will fetch from attribute.

Comment: so element will look like: <button class="followlink" data-content="content to be display">

Comment: data-content="<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/followup-popup.phtml')->tohtml();?>"">

Comment: Having get content inside the double quotes naturally gives me the entire thing that is within the quotes as is...any alternate of this/.

Comment: Either create DOM dynamic and get from ajax request of content and pull it in newly added DOM

Comment: That will display delayed but we can do it as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a javascript file is not interpreted by the PHP engine. You'll need to either modify your server's rules to process that file with PHP, or change the extension to `.php`. You'll also need to change the resulting content-type before outputting anything:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the JS as PHP OR externalise the PHP:

Do this in your PHP file:

```
<script>var content = "<?php echo json_encode($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/followup-popup.phtml')->tohtml());?>"</script>  
<script src="yourjsfile.js"></script>
```

and have `content: content` in the js file